# Send chat message, via PHP to SkypeID, using any PHP class and Skype protocol, without involving Skype messenger to be installed

Tags: php, zend-framework, centos, messaging, skype

I have a Call center application. Where users are online. And when a service is required i need to alert or send a notice to one of our operator using Chat message only.

But i would like to send it from server running with PHP in cross platform ex: CentOS or Solaris or FreeBSD or Xyz, without having a SkypeGUI apps running, but with my own commandline based instance.

Can we not do that? With Skype and PHP outside Windows platform (we never used windows as server unfortunately) ?

Follow up: looks good and great job done.
http://labs.gree.jp/Top/OpenSource/Skype-en.html but they say it works with linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tried this one: http://labs.gree.jp/Top/OpenSource/Skype-en.html
but they say it works with linux.

Answer (score 0):

http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=317291 looks like its windows only.

skype is pretty closed, might want to use something like xmpp etc. or get a windows box for the skype